# How does \usepackage differ from a simple \include or \input?

Tags: package-writing

What does `\usepackage` do that is different than `\input` or `\include`? Does it simply import the commands in the package file to the current document or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

More complicated. `\usepackage`:

- *can* check that the package is newer than a specified version date
- *can* have options specified for loading the package
- *can* inherit options from the `\documentclass` line
- only loads `.sty` files
- checks that it is only called after `\documentclass` and before `\begin{document}`
- ensures catcodes are correct for LaTeX package syntax (`\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`) even in the presence of `expl3` catcode environments
- performs assorted housekeeping, including adding the package details to the results given by `\listfiles`
- doesn't load the definitions of a package more than once
- checks that if a package is loaded more than once, the same options have been requested

Whereas `\input` simply starts reading the file requested as if it had literally been pasted at that point in the document. It can be used to input document text and/or preamble code, for example.

`\include` is only suitable for inserting document text after `\begin{document}`, and in fact is geared quite specifically around being used for chapters or parts of document. It performs addition actions over `\input`, such as starting a new page (with `\clearpage`) and changing the `.aux` file so that `\includeonly` produces correct results.

Comment: ...also, `\usepackage` only works on `.sty`.

Comment: also make sure that nothing bad happens if you load the same package twice

Comment: thx :) had to rush off before being complete…

Comment: And (in new latex versions) disables active expl3-catcodes and reenables them after the package.  So `\ExplSyntaxOn \usepackage{whatever}  some expl3-code` works fine.

Comment: although i suppose it's possible, it would be very odd to use`\include` in the preamble.

Comment: @barbarabeeton — thanks, I added a couple more sentences.